# B2C: Can I change my AppId URI without it being a breaking change?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to change the Application URI of one of my B2C applications. Unfortunately, the old URI stops working a couple of seconds after I change it.

> AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.

I would like to give my clients at least a couple of days to update their apps. My first idea was to first switch the applications to use the clientId as the scope, but I can't seem to get it to work with the defined API scopes.

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=45be975b-eb28-438f-aab3-508b9d1d5288
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://{{tenant}}.onmicrosoft.com/MyApplication/MyReadScope
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
```

I can get a successfull authentication when using the `clientId` instead of the AppId Uri, but this is missing `MyReadScope`. All requests I tried with `MyReadScope` fail to go trough.

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=45be975b-eb28-438f-aab3-508b9d1d5288
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob
&response_mode=query
&scope=45be975b-eb28-438f-aab3-508b9d1d5288  // How can I put MyReadScope here?
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new application registration to represent the API. Expose the same permissions as the old one. Assign permissions from your front end app registration to the new app registration. Your APIs will need to accept tokens from 2 audiences whilst the Applications update their scope params.